# How to calculate difference between keys and values in php

Tags: php, arrays, difference

I have two types of arrays:

```
1:
$array1["a"][] = "value1";
$array1["a"][] = "value2";
$array1["b"][] = "value3";

2:
$array2["0"] = "a";
```

What I need now is to somehow find difference between these two arrays. I need to filter out array1 by key, which is located in array2 value. I have tried doing the following:

```
array_diff(array_keys($array1), array_values($array2));
```

But I get the following error on that line:
`ErrorException Array to string conversion`

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you revise your question and add your PHP code?

Comment: That line does not produce that error. Are you trying to `echo` that diff…?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
   if( array_search ($key , $array2 ))
    unset($array1[$key]);
```

If $array1 needs to have the values, you just need to put the diff in $array1 :

```
$array1 = array_diff(array_keys($array1), array_values($array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you constructed your arrays, it should work.  The following code (based on your question) worked:

```
<?php
$array1=array("a" => array(),"a" => array(),"b" => array());
$array2=array("0"=>"a");
print_r(array_keys($array1));
echo("<br/>");
print_r(array_values($array2));
echo("<br/>");
print_r(array_diff(array_keys($array1), array_values($array2)));       
>
```

This results in:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b )
Array ( [0] => a )
Array ( [1] => b )
```